# How do I connect 2 Java websocket server applications in Docker?

Tags: java, spring, docker, websocket

I have 2 Java Spring Boot applications that I connect by localhost port 81. The code is fine as it works in Eclipse. When I use docker I try to expose the ports and it fails. I can't get the docker images to connect with each other in 2 separate docker terminals.

The server code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringGetApplication.class, args);
        try {
            final int portNumber = 81;
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);

            while (true) {
                // SOCKET MESSAGE SENDER
                // SOCKET SENDS MESSAGE THEN CLOSES
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os, true);

                // PW, PRINTWRITER SENDS STRINGS TO OTHER SERVER
                pw.println("Hello");

                // BUFFEREDREADER READS OTHER SERVER'S MESSAGES
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                // WHILE LOOP TO KEEP READING LINE WHEN THE INPUTS ARE COMING
                String answer = null;
                while ((answer = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(answer);
                }

                pw.println("I HAVE SUCCESSFULLY RECIEVED YOUR DATA");
                pw.close();
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {     }
    }
```

The client code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringGetApplication.class, args);

        try {
            final String host = "localhost";
            final int portNumber = 81;

            System.out.println("Creating server socket on port " + portNumber);
            Socket socket = new Socket(host, portNumber);

            // READS RESPONSE FROM THE SERVER
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            // PRINTWRITER USES SOCKET OUTPUT TO SEND THE DATA OUT TO THE OTHER SERVER
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            System.out.println("server says:" + br.readLine());

            String outputTextToCC = "HOWDY THERE, i'M THE CLIENT";
            // OUT SENDS THE STRING TO THE OTHER SERVER
            out.println(outputTextToCC);
            out.println("FINISH");

            // READS RESPONSE FROM OTHER SERVER
            System.out.println("server says:" + br.readLine());
            br.close();
            socket.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {     }
    }
```

I created Docker images for both of them and I run the 2 images on separate Docker terminals.

- Terminal 1 (My Server App): `docker run --expose=81 contactcentre2`
- Terminal 2 (My Client App): `docker run --expose=81 contactcentretest`

[image]

I tried exposing the port 81 but my client application still can't connect to the other server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your container, your application don't know what is "localhost".

If you use your network IP it will work. Better, use docker networking or compose :

https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/#the-default-bridge-network

https://docs.docker.com/compose/

You will find an exemple here :
https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/

And end with something like this :

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    image: server-img
    ports:
    - "81:81"
  client:
    image: client-img
    links:
    - server
```

Then, replace "localhost" by "server".

PS : you don't need to expose a port from your client.

Comment: The solution I found was actually very simple from reading the link: https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/#the-default-bridge-network you provided. Run the application in Docker Toolbox by: '$ docker run --network=host [imageName]' for both docker images to connect them on localhost.